# Sonatype nexus caching for local file system

Tags: nexus

I have a use case in which we are deploying golfing binary to a hosted type nexus repository. Is there a way we can use nexus to determine if the golang binary exists on a local VM, if not then download it from Nexus. If yes, compare the checksum with local binary to the one hosted and use the cached copy ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you would want to do is check for go's existence via a bash script or something akin, and if it doesn't exist then download from the known URL, install, etc...